# Django - Get HTTP Response on Web app by sending HTTP Request from Postman

Tags: python, django, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm using chrome-extension [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) for sending HTTP POST requests to my Django web application. The request is received successfully on my web app and after handling the request, when I send the HTTP response back, it shows the response on the Postman but I expect it to send on my web application so that some result is displayed (`contents`)

```
return render_to_response("logs/logs.html", {'contents': contents}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Is the response you get on Postman correct?

Comment: Yes! It is correct. But my app is running somewhere else and I want the response to go there. Request should come from Postman but my app should receive the response. Currently I'm running it locally on http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: You mean you want your app to respond to postman, and to itself?

Comment: To itself NOT Postman meaning if the Postman sends some request then my app should send the response back to itself like refreshing the page or sending some content back

Comment: So you mean user 1 is logged in in their browser. Incoming request hits django from postman, django updates users page?

Comment: Yes exactly! It should update my web app's page in above case `logs.html` !

Comment: But... that makes no sense. A response is returned to the client that requested it. And you can't make a web page refresh from somewhere else.

Comment: Isn't there any work around someone would send a request to me and I can get the data and use it on my own web app?